# Exclamation (!) in routes using angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a project where I am using Angularjs (1.x) as web framework. In that app, I needed routing, so I am using [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). I configured the routes in my app and its working fine, but **exclamation(!)** in routes is not clear to me and why these exclamation comes to routes.

Also, I saw demo example code provided by `angular ui router` . In [Hello World tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld#live-demo), I observed that routes are with **hash(#)** but not with **exclamation(!)** eg: `https://some_url/#/home`

but in [Hello Solar System tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem#live-demo) routes are with **hash(#)** and **exclamation(!)** eg. `https://some_url/#!/hello`.

Config for `angular ui router` in both tutorials are in same way. Thats why I am not able to understand what exactly is making the difference in both of them. So, I need help to understand this.

Any useful suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In new  version of `angularjs` you see `/#!` and in old version you see just `/#`

Comment: @Hadi: What do you mean by new version and old version of `angularjs` ?

Comment: please see this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52

Comment: This change was introduced in version 1.6.0. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#location-due-to

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet, that link is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

To let everyone know the answer for this question, adding what I understood from comments.

This change can be observed in angular version > 1.6.x. In previous version it was like just `#` (hash bang) only.
To get url like `#` way only, you can simply write in this way,

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

This change was introduced in `version 1.6.0`, which you can see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#location-due-to.

Also, adding here what is written there:

> The hash-prefix for `$location` hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string "" to the bang "!". If your application does not use `HTML5 mode` or is being run on browsers that do not support `HTML5 mode`, and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then client side URLs will now contain a "!" prefix. For example, rather than mydomain.com/#/a/b/c will become mydomain.com/#!/a/b/c.